# Is it possible to make all the inputs to class.__init__() as attributes in one line?

Tags: python, class, attributes

Most of the Python classes I have seen look like this (from the tutorial):

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, name, surname, birthdate, address, telephone, email):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.birthdate = birthdate

        self.address = address
        self.telephone = telephone
        self.email = email
```

Is there a way to have all the inputs to **init** as attributes without typing them one at a time line by line?

This is not just for data storage and I have other methods withing the class.

I like to do sth like this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, name, surname, birthdate, address, telephone, email):
        for name, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, name, value)
```

So the class cannot be initiated with any random variable but then I am not typing the `self.item = item` for each item.

Comment: This is a fairly contrived example class. Most classes you write won't have 6 fields that are directly supplied by the constructor parameters like this. If you do have something like this in the real world, a Named Tuple or something similar is likely more appropriate.

Comment: I'm not sure but probably module [attrs](https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs) tries to resolve this problem. You have to define class's attributes and you don't have to write `__init__` for them.

Comment: If you're on (or can upgrade to) 3.7, use [`@dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html).

Comment: This is not just for storing the data. I have methods as well. But want to simplify the init and not write all those lines one at a time.

Comment: If you're not using keyword arguments, _what_ determines the class instance's attribute name each argument corresponds to (as well as which ones are valid)?

Answer (score 3):

For positional arguments you could do something like

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        names = ('attr_name_1', 'attr_name_2', ..., 'attr_name_n')
        for name, value in zip(names, args):
            setattr(self, name, value)
```

If you want to make sure you are getting the amount of values you need here you can check `len(args) == len(names)`

With keyword arguments it's just

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for name, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, name, value)
```

Again, if you want to check that the arguments are the ones you expect you can store the expected keys in a set (say `names`) and check `names == set(kwargs.keys())`

Anyway, if you want to use your class to basically store that data you can use `dataclasses`. Taken from the official Python3.7 documentation:

```py
@dataclass
class InventoryItem:
    '''Class for keeping track of an item in inventory.'''
    name: str
    unit_price: float
    quantity_on_hand: int = 0

    def total_cost(self) -> float:
        return self.unit_price * self.quantity_on_hand
```

Note that for earlier Python versions `dataclasses` is not part of the Python Standard Library but can be installed as a regular package (e.g. `pip install dataclasses`)

Comment: Thanks. This is not for storing data, I have methods in this class as well. The solution looks good, but I want to have control over on what is getting passed to the class. With the solution using keyword arguments, someone can initiate the class with any variable that they pass to it. I like that to be fixed and from the variable list provided in the __init__ def. I am going to update he OP to be more clear.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be one option (maybe not the most pythonic way though):

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, name, surname):
        for item in inspect.signature(A).parameters:
            setattr(self, item, eval(item))
```

With the above, the name and surname have to be provide when initiating the class, but I do not need to do the assignment witin **init**() one line at a time.